# How to handle Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: react-native

I am trying to open my app and it doesn't apear.

I only get this error message.

Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 19000) from /192.168.1.232 (port 55968) after 10000ms

This problem is since i changed my cellphone, but i got the app also on my new one.

Comment: trying again gives me the same error just diffrent numbers at the last port and ms